# Java failed linking references

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm beginner in android, and I get an error when compiled with "geofirestore" library in the api 27. But in api 28 I don't get this error.

Android Studio Error:

[image: image from android studio error]

Comment: You need to expand each resource to see those errors

Comment: What are the errors from the expanded resource? Please responde with @.